# How to make a template with derived behavior?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have a template `Conditional` which returns `value` according to the boolean expression:

```cpp
template<bool C, typename C1, typename C2>
struct Conditional {
};

template<typename C1, typename C2>
struct Conditional<true, C1, C2> {
    typedef C1 value;
};

template<typename C1, typename C2>
struct Conditional<false, C1, C2> {
    typedef C2 value;
};
```

```cpp
<Conditional<(0 != 1), Int<0>, Int<1>>::value; // Int<0>
<Conditional<(0 == 1), Int<0>, Int<1>>::value, // Int<1>
```

I want to make a `ConditionalInteger` template where his behavior derives from `Condition`

```cpp
ConditionalInteger<(0 != 1), 0, 1>::value == 0; // true
ConditionalInteger<(0 == 1), 0, 1>::value == 1  // false
```

With straight forward approach it works:

```cpp
template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger {
};

template<int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger<true,N1,N2> {
    static constexpr int value = N1;
};

template<int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger<false,N1,N2> {
    static constexpr int value = N2;
};
```

How do I implement it using `Conditional`?

With the next try, I get an error:

> No type named ‘value’ in ‘struct IntWrapper<0>’

```cpp
template<int N>
struct IntWrapper {
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger {
    using value = typename Conditional<C, typename IntWrapper<N1>::value, typename IntWrapper<N2>::value>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger {
    static constexpr int value = 
        Conditional<C, IntWrapper<N1>, IntWrapper<N2>>::value::value;
};

static_assert(ConditionalInteger<true, 2, 3>::value == 2);
static_assert(ConditionalInteger<false, 2, 3>::value == 3);
```

`Conditional` accepts types, and you give it two types: `IntWrapper<N1>` and `IntWrapper<N2>`. It returns a type `Conditional<C, IntWrapper<N1>, IntWrapper<N2>>::value`, which is `IntWrapper<N>`. Then you extract `N` from this type with one more `::value`. You don't need `typename`s here.

You can also derive `ConditionalInteger` from `IntWrapper`:

```
template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger : IntWrapper<
    Conditional<C, IntWrapper<N1>, IntWrapper<N2>>::value::value> {};
```

More verbose implementation:

```
template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger {
    using Int = typename Conditional<C, IntWrapper<N1>, IntWrapper<N2>>::value;
    static constexpr int value = Int::value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the simplest way would be to not use specialization at all:

```
template<bool C, int N1, int N2>
struct ConditionalInteger {
    static constexpr int value = C ? N1 : N2;
};
```

The ternary operator can be used in constexpr context.

But then I'd use something like this:

```
template<auto c>
using constant = std::intergral_constant<decltype(c), c>;

using my_constant = constant<condition ? 4 : 8>;
```

No need to define a new call, simply add some aliases.